# How to use the comparison in GHC.TypeLits

Tags: haskell, types, ghc

I ran into problems playing with [GHC.TypeLits](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-TypeLits.html). Consider the following GADT:

```hs
data Foo :: Nat -> * where
  SmallFoo :: (n <= 2)  => Foo n
  BigFoo   :: (3 <= n)  => Foo n
```

My understanding was, that now for every `n`, the type `Foo n` is populated by exactly one value (which is either a SmallFoo or a BigFoo depending on the value of `n`).

But if I now want to construct a concrete instance as follows:

```hs
myFoo :: Foo 4
myFoo = BigFoo
```

Then GHC (7.6.2) spits out the following error message:

```
No instance for (3 <= 4) arising from a use of `BigFoo'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (3 <= 4)
In the expression: BigFoo
In an equation for `myFoo': myFoo = BigFoo
```

This seems odd - I expected there to be a predefined instance for such type level nat comparisons. How can I express these kinds of constraints in my data constructor using type level naturals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solver for TypeLists is not in GHC right now, according to [status page](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Status/GHC-7.8) there are some chances that it will be in GHC 7.8 in october or something.

Maybe it's better to use [other packages](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-level-tf) for now.

Answer (score 3):

This compiles on the current head of the [type-nats](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/a3506674ab786535713b1e55d331ae0d73b1a8ac) branch, which should (hopefully) be merged for 7.8.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module X where

import GHC.TypeLits

data Foo :: Nat -> * where
  SmallFoo :: (n <= 2)  => Foo n
  BigFoo   :: (3 <= n)  => Foo n

myFoo :: Foo 4
myFoo = BigFoo
```

Where if `myFoo` is changed to be of type `Foo 1` it fails to compile, presumably because the `x <= y` class constraint is expanded to the `(x <=? y) ~ 'True` equality constraint:

```
$ /Source/ghc/inplace/bin/ghc-stage1 /tmp/blah.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling X                ( /tmp/blah.hs, /tmp/blah.o )

/tmp/blah.hs:16:13:
    Couldn't match type ‛3 <=? 1’ with ‛'True’
    In the expression: BigFoo
    In an equation for ‛myFoo’: myFoo = BigFoo
```